# How to edit text in a text file using StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am creating an application which displays the contents of a text file in a listbox. I have created an edit form to edit items. The edits are displayed in the listbox but I am finding it difficult to save them to the text file. Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Here is the code for my edit form:

```
    public static ArrayList switches = new ArrayList();
    public static frmSwitches frmkeepSwitches = null;
    public static string inputDataFile = "LeckySafe.txt";
    ListBox listBoxSwitches;

    public frmEditSwitch(ListBox lstSwitch)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxSwitches = lstSwitch;
    }

    public string NewText
    {
        get
        {
            return txtSerialNo.Text;
        }
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSerialNo.Text = "";
    }

    private void frmEditSwitch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSerialNo.Text = listBoxSwitches.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSwitches.frmkeepSwitches.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxSwitches.Items[listBoxSwitches.SelectedIndex] = txtSerialNo.Text;
        frmSwitches.frmkeepSwitches.Show();
        this.Close(); 
    }        
}
```

Code on the main form:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    frmEditSwitch tempEditSwitch = new frmEditSwitch(lstSwitch);
    tempEditSwitch.Show();
    frmkeepSwitches.Hide();
    //My line
    lstSwitch.Items[lstSwitch.SelectedIndex] = tempEditSwitch.NewText;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `StreamWriter` anywhere in your code. Of course, I'm also not seeing where you are reading the file either. Perhaps you can show the relevant parts of the code (I don't think the reset button code is relevant, for example). Also, what part of using `StreamWriter` you're having a problem with...

Comment: What is _frmkeepSwitches_?

Comment: what do you mean by `I am finding it difficult to save them to the text file.` do a search on how to create and save textfile using StreamWriter.. also do you even use the debugger to step through your own code..?

Comment: I've been using streamwriter for my add form but everytime I use it for the edit form it never saves the changes to the text file

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(inputDataFile))
{
     foreach (var item in lstSwitch.Items)
     {
         writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
     }
}
```

In general, only show relevant code.